# Create a sparse distance matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have the following vector:

```
a <- 1:10
b <- c(100, 300, 400, 120, 131,
       450, 400, 432, 111, 123)
rep_ab <- unlist(lapply(a, function(x) rep(x, times = b[x])))
length(rep_ab) == sum(b)
# TRUE

I would like to create a distance matrix using the vector `rep_ab`. Usually, I would use the following code:

mat <- outer(rep_ab, rep_ab, FUN = "-")
```

But since this matrix is too large, I would like to create this distance matrix using sparse matrices. Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is `distSparse`  in `qlcMatrix`, but I'm not sure how useful this will be in your case. Your resulting distance matrix will be approximately 90% non-zero, so you still have 0.9*n^2 (~4 million) entries in your matrix.